# Parsing numbers into two 2D arrays from file

Tags: python, arrays

I have this in a file:

```
1 0 2 4 3
4 6 5 2 1
4 4 5 2 1
5 6 8 5 3
-
3 2 4 0
3 2 4 2
0 7 3 3
3 3 0 2
1 3 2 2
```

I need to split each one into its own matrix when the line is `'-'`. What I have done so far:

```
    with open(fname) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        subArray = []
        firstMatrix= []
        for line in content:
            if line.strip() == '-':
                break
            for digit in line.split():
                subArray.append(digit)
            firstMatrix.append(subArray)
```

But that puts all digits for the matrix before `'-'` into an array of array. I tried inserting `if line == '-' break` inside it but to no avail. Final output needs to be:

```
[[1, 0, 2, 4, 3],
[4, 6, 5, 2, 1],
[4, 4, 5, 2, 1],
[5, 6, 8, 5, 3]]

[[3, 2, 4, 0],
[3, 2, 4, 2],
[0, 7, 3, 3],
[3, 3, 0, 2],
[1, 3, 2, 2]]
```

each saved into its respective variable: firstMatrix, secondMatrix.

Comment: They are called lists in Python, unless you are specifically using an `array` object or something from numpy or xarrays or similar.

Comment: better use list and `matrix[0]` instead of `firstMatrix`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this as a generator.

```
def get_matrix(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        matrix = []
        for line in fin:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '-':
                yield matrix
                matrix = []
            else:        
                matrix.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])
        else:
            yield matrix # yield last matrix in case file doesn't end with '-'

>>> for m in get_matrix('matrix_file.txt'):
    print(m)

[[1, 0, 2, 4, 3], [4, 6, 5, 2, 1], [4, 4, 5, 2, 1], [5, 6, 8, 5, 3]]
[[3, 2, 4, 0], [3, 2, 4, 2], [0, 7, 3, 3], [3, 3, 0, 2], [1, 3, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In addition to printing the generator, I added another array to append for each iteration, so I can have access to each matrix later on.

Comment: You're welcome. You can just do `matrix_groups = list(get_matrix('matrix_file.txt'))` instead of a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the entire contents of the file are in variable content

```
import re
matrices = re.split('-', content)
downMatrix = [[mat.split() for mat in matrix.splitlines()][1:] for matrix in matrices]
```

Comment: Umm.. shouldn't the [1:] be [0:] or just [:] ?

Comment: `[1:]` because it's specific to this problem. the first element of the list is an escape character. To exclude it, slicing the list from 1st index to last.

Comment: Okay, yes with the first character there it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

```
current = 0
curr_mat = []
all_matrix = []

with open(fname) as f:
   line = f.readlines()
   line = line.split()
   if len(line) == 1 and line[0] == '-':
       count += 1
       all_matrix.append(curr_mat)
       curr_mat = []

   else:
       curr_mat.append(line)
```

all_matrix will have all the matrix after processing were index `0` will have matrix0, `1` index will have matrix1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use break inside of list comprehension

You should process your data first

```
processed_content = []

temp_array = []
for line in content:
  if line == '-':
    processed_content.append(temp_array)
    temp_array=[]
  else:
    temp_array.append(line)
processed_content.append(temp_array)

matrix = [[[digit for digit in line.split()] for line in array] 
          for array in processed_content]
```

matrix[0] contains first matrix .. etc

Answer (score 1):

This works.

saves all matrices to an array rather than variable names..

```
f = open('file1.txt')

matrices = []

matrix = []
for line in f.readlines():
  str = line.translate(None, '\n\r ')
  if(str[0] != '-'):
    matrix.append(list(str))
  else:
    matrices.append(matrix)
    matrix = []

#depends if code ends in '-' char
matrices.append(matrix)

print(matrices)
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `subArray` in your code:

```
for digit in line.split():
    subArray.append(digit)
firstMatrix.append(subArray)
```

So the `subArray` will have all digits in the matrix.

Try this:

```
matrices = [[] for _ in range(2)] # since you only have 2 matrices in text file
no_matrix = 0                     # matrices[no_matrix], you get the idea

with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        subArray = []
        if line.strip() == '-':
            no_matrix += 1
        else:
            for digit in line.split():
                subArray.append(digit)
            matrices[no_matrix].append(subArray)

for matrix in matrices:
    print(matrix)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
txt = open('stackFile.txt')
file = txt.read()
splitedFile = file.split(' ')
# print m
allmatrix = []
data = []
c = list()
for n in splitedFile:

    # print "n",n
    if '\n' in n:
        if '-' in n:
            v = n.split('\n-\n')
            c.append(v[0])          
            data.append(c)
            allmatrix.append(data)
            c = list()
            data = list()
            c.append(v[1])


        else:

            v = n.split('\n')
            c.append(v[0])          
            data.append(c)
            c = list()
            c.append(v[1])

    else:
        c.append(n)
updateFinalMatrix = allmatrix.append(data)

for matrix in allmatrix:
    print matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a clarification of @Arjun's post (ie note no "\n" at the end of the dash):

```
import re
content="\
1 0 2 4 3\n\
4 6 5 2 1\n\
4 4 5 2 1\n\
5 6 8 5 3\n\
-\
3 2 4 0\n\
3 2 4 2\n\
0 7 3 3\n\
3 3 0 2\n\
1 3 2 2\n"

matrices = re.split('-', content)
firstMatrix, secondMatrix = [[mat.split() for mat in matrix.splitlines()] for matrix in matrices]
print(firstMatrix,"\n",secondMatrix)
```

Which gives you the required answer:

```
[['1', '0', '2', '4', '3'], ['4', '6', '5', '2', '1'], ['4', '4', '5', '2', '1'], ['5', '6', '8', '5', '3']]
[['3', '2', '4', '0'], ['3', '2', '4', '2'], ['0', '7', '3', '3'], ['3', '3', '0', '2'], ['1', '3', '2', '2']]
```